# Solving a simple JS script

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me fix this? I did research but can't make it work :(

```html
<h1 id="fruit">apples</h1>

<h2>I like<span id="sentence"></span></h2>

<script>
  document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = fruit;
  const sentence = document.getElementById("fruit");
</script>
```

---

Basically I want the h2 to display "I like apples", using the id of h1

Thanks.

Comment: ```const fruit = document.getElementById("fruit").innerText;
document.getElementById("sentence").innerText = fruit;```

Comment: Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: As you see from the resulting "I like[object HTMLHeadingElement]", `fruit` is the element itself. You can use its `innerHTML`, but for textual content `innerText` is more straightforward. Just make them match, so `x.innerHTML = y.innerHTML` or `x.innerText = y.innerText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the innerHTML of sentence to the innerHTML of fruit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="fruit">apples</h1>

<h2>I like <span id="sentence"></span></h2>

<script>
document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```